# Swift Task.init() takes 1.14s for the same operation that takes 0.73s with a completion handler

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, completion

I tried to refactor a Firebase operation from the old completion handler to the new `Task.init()` and it seems that the operation is now taking longer. Am I doing something wrong? Are the await calls not being done concurrently (which is the reason I am calling both operations at the same time and counting how many finished with the completion handler approach)? Any suggestions for what might be causing the slower execution time?

Thank you in advance.

1. Completion handler approach (0.73s)

   ---

   Previously I had this method:

   ```
   extension Firebase {
       static func getAll<T: Decodable>(_ subCollection: SubCollection,
                                        completion: @escaping (_ result: [T]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
           db.collection("userData").document(currentUser!.uid).collection("\(subCollection)").getDocuments(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
               var documents: [T] = []
               if let error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
               if let querySnapshot {
                   for document in querySnapshot.documents {
                       if let decodedDocument = try? document.data(as: T.self) { documents.append(decodedDocument) }
                       else { print("Failed to decode a retrieved document of type \(T.self) at getAll") }
                   }
               }
               completion(documents, error)
               AppNotification.post(.firebseOperationCompleted)
           })
       }
   }
   ```

   Which I would use like this:

   ```
   class Loading: UIViewController {

       var error: Error?
       var operationsCompleted = 0
       let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

       private func fetchData() {
           operationsCompleted = 0

           Firebase.getAll(.goals, completion: { (results: [Goal]?, error) in
               if let results { UltraDataStorage.goals = results }
               if let error { self.error = error }
               self.operationsCompleted += 1
           })

           Firebase.getAll(.ideas, completion: { (results: [Idea]?, error) in
               if let results { UltraDataStorage.ideas = results }
               if let error { self.error = error }
               self.operationsCompleted += 1
           })

       @objc func advanceWhenOperationsComplete(){
           print("Took \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start) seconds")
           if operationsCompleted == 2 {
               // Proceed if error is nil
           }
       }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           fetchData()
           AppNotification.observe(handler: self, name: .firebseOperationCompleted, function: #selector(advanceWhenOperationsComplete))
       }
   }
   ```
2. `Task.init()` approach (1.14s)

   ---

   Now, I updated the `getAll` function:

   ```
   extension Firebase {
       static func getAll<T: Decodable>(_ subCollection: SubCollection) async -> Result<[T], Error> {
           do {
               let documents = try await db.collection("userData").document(currentUser!.uid).collection("\(subCollection)").getDocuments()
               var decodedDocuments: [T] = []
               for document in documents.documents {
                   if let decodedDocument = try? document.data(as: T.self) { decodedDocuments.append(decodedDocument) }
                   else { print("Failed to decode a retrieved document of type \(T.self) at getAll") }
               }
               return.success(decodedDocuments)
           }
           catch { return.failure(error) }
       }
   }
   ```

   And I am now calling it like this

   ```
   class Loading: UIViewController {

       var error: Error?        
       let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

       private func fetchData() {
           Task.init(operation: {
               let goalsResult: Result<[Goal], Error> = await Firebase.getAll(.goals)
               switch goalsResult {
               case .success(let goals): UltraDataStorage.goals = goals
               case .failure(let error): self.error = error
               }

               let ideasResult: Result<[Idea], Error> = await Firebase.getAll(.ideas)
               switch ideasResult {
               case .success(let ideas): UltraDataStorage.ideas = ideas
               case .failure(let error): self.error = error
               }

               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.advanceWhenOperationsComplete()
               }
           })

       }

       func advanceWhenOperationsComplete(){
           print("Took \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start) seconds")
           // Proceed when the async operations are completed
       }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           fetchData()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What's the question? If you want to know what's occupying the time, use Instruments. That's what it's for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @matt, though I'm not sure what to make of this. https://ibb.co/fMZLXnR My question was why the same operation takes longer with async/await than it does with a completion handler.

Comment: The async-await rendition runs these two requests sequentially, whereas the completion-handler implementation is running them concurrently. Use a task group to run them in parallel. I can't test this (as you didn't provide us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but perhaps something like: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/ae11f378ebe896e6ffe9d80e410b7b09.

Comment: Ooh, that makes sense @Rob, thanks a lot for clarifying. I didn't know the requests won't be executed concurrently out of the box. And thank you for the other suggestions also. If this question gets reopened, I think what you shared here will be helpful to others too, so I would mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: question reopened @Rob should share his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference is likely a result that the completion handler pattern is running the requests concurrently, but the `async`-`await` rendition is performing them sequentially. The latter is awaiting the result of the first asynchronous request before even initiating the next asynchronous request.

To get them to run concurrently, you can either use the `async let` pattern (see [SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md)) or use a task group:

```swift
extension Firebase {
    static func getAll<T: Decodable>(_ subCollection: SubCollection) async throws -> [T] {
        try await db
            .collection("userData")
            .document(currentUser!.uid)
            .collection("\(subCollection)")
            .getDocuments()
            .documents
            .map { try $0.data(as: T.self) }
    }
}

// you could use `async let`

private func fetchData1() async throws {
    async let goals: [Goal] = Firebase.getAll(.goals)
    async let ideas: [Idea] = Firebase.getAll(.ideas)

    UltraDataStorage.goals = try await goals
    UltraDataStorage.ideas = try await ideas

    advanceWhenOperationsComplete()
}

// or task group

private func fetchData2() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { UltraDataStorage.goals = try await Firebase.getAll(.goals) }
        group.addTask { UltraDataStorage.ideas = try await Firebase.getAll(.ideas) }

        try await group.waitForAll()
    }

    advanceWhenOperationsComplete()
}
```

(These might not be 100% right, as I do not implementations for all of these types and methods and therefore cannot compile this, but hopefully it illustrates the idea. Notably, I am nervous about the thread-safety of `UltraDataStorage`, especially in the task group example. But, that is beyond the scope of this question.)

Bottom line, `async let` is an intuitive way to run tasks concurrently and is most useful when dealing with a fixed, limited number of asynchronous tasks. Task groups shine when dealing with a variable number of tasks. That’s not the case here, but I include it for the sake of completeness.

Note, I’ve taken the liberty of excising the `Result<[T], Error>` type, and instead `throw` the error.

Comment: Thanks again Rob, as I said I have tested the approach you suggested and it performs as expected. Thanks again for such a through and helpful answer.